# Run gatling project from an executable jar

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I have a small Gatling project which I would like to package through sbt and then run on different Linux/Windows machines with different JVM parameters. I tried already the `sbt package` command but that didn't work out. Anyone has done something similar before?

Answer (score 0):

Package doesn't include the dependencies of your project.

You need something like [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), [sbt-pack](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack) or [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager).
Then you can start your tests from within a main method (depending on the type of your package, e.g. java -jar fat-jar-name.jar).